# How to find residue of $f(z)= \frac{(\log z)^3}{z^2+1}$ at $z= i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to find residue of $f(z)= \frac{(\log z)^3}{z^2+1}$ at $z= i$ ?

I know that residue is coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-i}$, but how to get that series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$\frac{\log^3z}{z^2+1}=\frac{\frac{\log^3z}{z+i}}{z-i},$$the residue is $\frac{\log^3i}{2i}$.